# Calling function from main query Returns returns more than one row error. Function should loop to get matching values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need some help in solving this. I have regex table and transaction table with no matching ids between them so if you join its leads to Cartesian join. My requirement is to compare  column URL with REGCOL and return true or false. the function I am calling is from main query example given below but it gives error Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Transaction table :

| Column A | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Regex table :

| REGCOL | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Scenario 1 below gives error  Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addone(URL VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS STRING
as
$$

SELECT case when regexp_like(url, c.BUSINESS_RULES) then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS TEST  from config_REGEX c

$$;
```

```
select 
        e.page_path_clean as Business_Rules ,
       case when addone(e.page_path_clean) and NOT addone(e.page_path_clean) 
            THEN 'postsign'
            else 'other'
    END as page_category 
from Transactiontable e
```

Scenario 2 : Creates cartesian join and doesn't look like a good solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addone(url VARCHAR(16777216), BUSINESS_RULES VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS BOOLEAN
as
$$
SELECT  regexp_like(url, BUSINESS_RULES)   
$$;
```

```
select 
        e.page_path_clean as Business_Rules,
       case when addone('www.postsign.com', c.BUSINESS_RULES) and NOT addone(e.page_path_clean) 
            THEN 'postsign'
            else 'other'
    END as page_category 
   from  "ANALYTICS_PROD"."GOOGLE_ANALYTICS"."GA_EVENTS"  e , config_REGEX c
```

Regex table can be big and transaction table is also huge. Looks like looping doesn't work inside function. What would be the best solution in this case.

Comment: A function can only return a single value (unless it is a table function). In your first attempt, the SQL in the function will return a value for every row in the table config_REGEX (run the SQL on its own to see this). Please update your question with the single value that you want your function to return and the logic used to determine that value

Answer (score 0):

I would say in function simply aggreagte the result before returning.
So if pattern is matched with any of business rule you will get true in return

and go with option 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addone(URL VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS STRING
as
$$

SELECT BOOLOR_AGG(case when regexp_like(url, c.BUSINESS_RULES) then TRUE ELSE FALSE END)::varchar AS TEST  from config_REGEX c

$$;
```